# error: method onCreate(Bundle) is already defined in class MainActivity public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) { ^

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am new to programming and I was making an app in Android Studio. I wanted to make several buttons open a new Activity, but when repeating the process for the other buttons it gave me this error.

There's my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {
    private Button button1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.octubre);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                openActivity2();
            }
        });
    }

    public void openActivity2() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    private Button button2;

    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent startIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Activity3.class);
        startActivity(startIntent);

        button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.aucas);
        button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                openActivity3();
            }
        });
    }

    public void openActivity3() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity3.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you accidentally name multiple classes `MainActivity`?

Comment: Yes I have changed that but the error continues.

Comment: Try pressing Ctrl + Shift + F, and search for "onCreate". You should get exactly three results, with one in each of your three `Activities`.

Comment: You messed up your code. Can I know how much buttons you're using and why you're using `public void onClick(View v)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have two redundant onCreate methods. Activity class should have only one onCreate method. Please remove the method '*public void onCreate(Bundle icicle)*' from your code. The onCreate method shown on the above code hasn't any issue. So, you can leave it as it is. I hope this will solve your issue.